# Merge Vectorfile Outputs from Model Batchprocess in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, batch, qgis-modeler

I have written a model in QGIS 3.6 that allows to vectorize the outlines of raster layers containing measurement data. I run this model as a batch process to vectorize several field outlines in one go.

In the end, I want to have a single file containing my field outlines. The Batchprocess, however, creates one output for each input. Until now I just store all these output files (output_1.gpkg, output_2.gpkg,..., output_X.gpkg) in a temporary folder on my desktop and use the SAGA Merge Vector Layers to merge all the outputs into one file.

I am now trying to put this last step directly into the script, but since the outputs are the result of the script itself and only created in the batchmode, there is no file I can hand to the merge tool as an input. Is there a way to use a path to the temporary folder as an input in the Modeler?

I use QGIS 3.6 on a Windows 7 PC.